# Not getting web output

Tags: python, flask

I used Flask command in my program for first time. Following was the bit of code I wrote:

```
from flask import Flask,jsonify, request

app = Flask(__name__)



@app.route("/")
def hello_world():
    return "Hello World!"


if (__name__ == "__main__"):
    app.run(debug=True)
```

This code was written by me in IDLE Shell 3.8-32 bit and the output should had come in a web browser. But it didn't came. I just got the following output from IDLE:

```
* Serving Flask app "sa" (lazy loading)
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: on
 * Restarting with stat
```

Comment: Were you expecting the browser to open automatically?  No, you have to do that yourself, and type in the address of your server - something like `127.0.0.1:8000`, although I'm not sure what port number Flask uses if you don't specify one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
app.run(host=0.0.0.0, port=5000, debug=True)
```

You can change your port number to your convenience.